# C# Split a string of integers into an IEnumerable<int>

Tags: c#, parsing, syntax

I need to convert a string of comma separated integers into a list of integers.

What is the best way to do this?

I can do it below but am worried about the performance - Is there a better more efficient way to do this?

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetListOfIds()
{
    string Ids = "1,4,5,7,12"; // would be passed into method
    List<int> _result = Ids.Split(',')
                           .ToList()
                           .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
                           .ToList();

    return _result;
}
```

Comment: If you're worried about performance then the right thing to do is to *measure your performance*. Then you'll know whether you're worrying unnecessarily or not.

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861833/split-string-extension-with-generic-type

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no need to call `ToList`, but otherwise your code looks fine:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetListOfIds(string ids)
{
    return ids.Split(',').Select(item => int.Parse(item));
}
```

You may also want to consider adding error handling in case the input string is invalid:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetListOfIds(string ids)
{
    foreach (string part in ids.Split(','))
    {
        int x;
        if (!int.TryParse(part, out x))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("The value {0} cannot be parsed as an integer.", part),
                "ids");
        }
        else
        {
            yield return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would shorten `item => int.Parse(item)` to just `int.Parse`. (No significant gain in speed, mostly pure aesthetics.)

Comment: A trick I like is to define an extension method `static int? MyTryParse(this string s) { int x; return int.TryParse(s, out x) ? (int?)x : (int?)null; }` and then you can do `foreach(int? part in ids.Split(',').Select(s=>s.MyTryParse()))` ... Anything you can do to move the mutation of the variable to a lower level is goodness.

Comment: Thanks mark, will use the first suggestion as I am not worried if it fails to parse - I am in charge of the string, so if I configure this wrong(should never happen!) its a straight out exception

Answer (score 1):

You may at least omit first ToList() statement - so it will be

```
  List<int> _result = Ids.Split(',').Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToList();
```

Comment: Since the stated requirement is for an `IEnumerable<int>`, there's no need for the second `ToList()`, either.

Answer (score 0):

You  can probably loop on the split result and do a yield return int.Parse... but I would not expect big differences unless you have really many items in the original string.

Comment: I wouldn't expect much of a difference regardless of the size of the string.  Why would you?

Comment: because in that way we would ignore any ToString() and the enumerable would be scrolled/scan only once from begin to end with an iterator, ToList scans it all at every call. What I had in mind is exactly the second code block in Mark's answer which got voted and flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stringify.Library nuget package

1. Example 1 (Default delimiter is implicitly taken as comma)
   `var ids = "1, 4, 5, 7, 12";
   var splitComma = new StringConverter().ConvertTo<List<int>>(ids);`
2. Example 2 (Specifying the delimiter explicitly)
   `var ids = "1; 4; 5; 7; 12";

   var splitColon = new StringConverter().ConvertTo<List<int>>(ids, new ConverterOptions { Delimiter = ';' });`