# Split string extension with generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, extension-methods, type-conversion

I would like to create a Split extension that would allow me to split any string to a strongly-typed list. I have a head start, but since I was going to reuse this in many projects, I would like to get input from the community (and so you can add it to your own toolbox ;) Any ideas from here?

```
public static class Converters
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Split<T>(this string source, char delimiter)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        //SPLIT TO INTEGER LIST
        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            return source.Split(delimiter).Select(n => int.Parse(n)) as IEnumerable<T>;
        }

        //SPLIT TO FLOAT LIST
        if (type == typeof(float))
        {
            return source.Split(delimiter).Select(n => float.Parse(n)) as IEnumerable<T>;
        }

        //SPLIT TO DOUBLE LIST
        if (type == typeof(double))
        {
            return source.Split(delimiter).Select(n => double.Parse(n)) as IEnumerable<T>;
        }

        //SPLIT TO DECIMAL LIST
        if (type == typeof(decimal))
        {
            return source.Split(delimiter).Select(n => decimal.Parse(n)) as IEnumerable<T>;
        }

        //SPLIT TO DATE LIST
        if (type == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return source.Split(delimiter).Select(n => DateTime.Parse(n)) as IEnumerable<T>;
        }

        //USE DEFAULT SPLIT IF NO SPECIAL CASE DEFINED
        return source.Split(delimiter) as IEnumerable<T>;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should/could use else if, instead of multiple single if statements. Only one is going to match.

Comment: @mfussenegger: Since each `if` block contains a `return` statement, then the `else` becomes redundant.

Comment: IMO, if your generic method relies on testing the type of the generic parameter, then it's probably not a good candidate for generics.

Comment: @Douglas oh my bad, guess I wasn't fully awake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I agree with Lee’s suggestion, I personally don’t think it’s worth defining a new extension method for something that may trivially be achieved with standard LINQ operations:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = "1,2,3".Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
```

Comment: I have to agree. Given the terseness of this answer, spinning it out to an extension method seems only to add noise.

Answer (score 9):

I'd add a parameter for the conversion function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Split<T>(this string source, Func<string, T> converter, params char[] delimiters)
{
    return source.Split(delimiters).Select(converter);
}
```

And you can call it as

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = "1,2,3".Split<int>(int.Parse, ',');
```

I would also consider renaming it to avoid confusion with the `String.Split` instance method since this complicates overload resolution, and behaves differently to the others.

EDIT: If you don't want to specify the conversion function, you could use type converters:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SplitConvert<T>(this string str, params char[] delimiters)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
    {
        return str.Split(delimiters).Select(s => (T)converter.ConvertFromString(s));
    }
    else throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot convert type");
}
```

This allows the conversion to be extended to other types rather than relying on a pre-defined list.

Comment: Thanks but kinda defeats the purpose of generic types and easy reusablity if I have to pass in the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Split<T>
      (this string source, char delimiter,Converter<string,T> func)
{
     return source.Split(delimiter).Select(n => func(n)));
}
```

**Example:**

```
"...".Split<int>(',',p=>int.Parse(p))
```

Or you can use Converter.ChangeType without define function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Split<T>(this string source, char delimiter)
{
     return source.Split(delimiter).Select(n => (T)Convert.ChangeType(n, typeof(T)));
}
```

Comment: +1, but note that the call could be more concise: `"...".Split(',', int.Parse)` instead of `"...".Split<int>(',',p=>int.Parse(p))`

Comment: @phoog, I think p=>int.Parse(p) is more flexible than int.Parse because you can use any overload of int.Parse() such as p=>int.Parse(p,,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint).

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this method. Parsing data types from strings (a sort of deserialization) is a very type- and content- sensitive process when you're dealing with data types more complex than an `int`. For example, `DateTime.Parse` parses the date [using the current culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), so your method is not going to provide consistent or reliable output for dates across systems. It also tries to parse the date *at all costs* so it might skip through what might be considered bad input in some situations.

The goal of *splitting any string into a strongly typed list* cannot really be accomplished with a single method that uses hard-coded conversions, especially if your goal is broad usability. Even if you do update it repeatedly with new conversions. The best way to go about it is just to `"1,2,3".Split(",").Select(x => whatever)` like Douglas suggested above. It's also very clear what sort of conversion is taking place.